# How to Create complex search Query for ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created ElasticSearch index with following mapping.
I need to write Complex Search query like find relevant Items on query result.
Ex.Find item having price= "100". Get ItemBrand from search result and then find other items having same ItemBrand.(Similar products).
Can anyone help me out?

```
PUT myindex-solvisoft2
{
"mappings": {
"ItemCategory":{
"properties": {Category":{"type": "text"},"IsActive":{"type": "boolean"},"Comment":{"type": "text" }}
},

"ItemBrand": {
"properties": {"Creator": {"type": "keyword"},"DateEffective": {"type": "date"},"DateTerminated": {"type": "date"},"Description": {"type": "text"},
"IsActive": {"type": "boolean"},"ItemBrand": {"type": "keyword"}}
},

"Item": {
"properties": {
"Comment": {"type": "text"},"Creator": {"type": "keyword"},"DateEffective": {"type": "date"},
"DateTerminated": {"type": "date"},"IsActive": {"type": "boolean"},"ItemBrand": {"type": "keyword"   },
"ItemDescription": { "type": "text"  },"ItemCategory": {"type": "keyword"},"ItemId": {"type": "integer" },
"Price": {"type": "double"  }    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well writing the query without running it would be quite challenging but I can break down the steps.

using boolean must, find out the records having price equal to 100.

after that you need to filter out the query and using fields you can search the the items having the same item brand.

It's not that much complex.

Comment: I dont want items from search result. Individual search should be initiated on the basis of first Result.ItemBrand.

Comment: Some what like this =>  Select * from Item where ItemBrand in (Select ItemBrand from Item where Price = 100 )

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for respective issue.Night be helpful for beginners if required.

```
GET myindex-solvisoft_similar_products/_search
{
"query": {
"bool": {
"filter": {
"term": {
"brand": "Microsoft"
}
}
}
},
"aggs": {
"colors": {
"terms": {
"field": "color"
}
},
"color_red": {
"filter": {
"term": {
"color": "red"
}
},
"aggs": {
"models": {
"terms": {
"field": "model"
}
}
}
}
},
"post_filter": {
"term": {
"color": "red"
}
}
}
```